# What types of errors will result from booting if system files have been lost to bad sectors?

Tags: bad-sectors

What types of errors will result from booting if one or more system files have been lost to bad sectors?

Answer (score 1):

There are thousands of system files.

- A substantial number are irrelevant (support for languages and hardware that don't apply to you, etc.).  If it was any of those, you might never know it.
- Many of the files are things you might use only occasionally, if at all (fonts, utilities, diagnostics, wizards, certain services, etc.).  It could be a long time after these are lost before you would have occasion to be aware of a problem.
- Getting to the things that are used regularly, many do not perform a critical function.  Over the course of using the computer, you might notice that some functions don't work, or some software has problems.
- Then there are files that are pretty fundamental to using the computer.  You could notice degraded performance, or some devices wouldn't operate, or the screen might have problems.  You might not be able to run some things you need.  Your user profile could be hosed, or various configuration information could be lost.
- Loss of files that are critical could leave the system unstable; Blue Screen of Death while you're using it or soon after boot.
- Certain of the critical files are required to start or successfully complete booting up.  Loss of those would prevent you from starting up the computer.